# Copying wordheader via vba adds line break

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following VBA macro which deletes the headers of a word document, then prints the document and then adds the header back. The header is basically only an image.

The problem is every time the macro is executed a line break is added in the header, which will move the main section down after some executions.

Here is the code I have:

```
Sub print()
    Dim oSec As Section
    Dim oHead As HeaderFooter

    For Each oSec In ActiveDocument.Sections
        For Each oHead In oSec.Headers
            If oHead.Exists Then oHead.Range.CopyAsPicture
                oHead.Range.Delete
        Next oHead
    Next oSec

    ActivePrinter = "Bullzip PDF Printer"

    Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, Item:= _
        wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, Copies:=1, Pages:="", PageType:= _
        wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=True, Background:=True, PrintToFile:=False, _
        PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, _
        PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0

    For Each oSec In ActiveDocument.Sections
        For Each oHead In oSec.Headers
            If oHead.Exists Then oHead.Range.Paste
        Next oHead
    Next oSec

End Sub
```

Can someone explain why an additional line is added each time the macro is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickest idea I can think of (possibly not the most elegant) is to delete additional paragraph which appears after pasting of the image. I assumed that additional paragraph is the last one. Therefore you second loop will looks as follows:

```
'...beginning of your code here
For Each oSec In ActiveDocument.Sections
    For Each oHead In oSec.Headers
        If oHead.Exists Then oHead.Range.Paste
            'new line to delete additional paragraph
            oHead.Range.Paragraphs(oHead.Range.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Delete
    Next oHead
Next oSec
'...rest of your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into similar issue with footer. Every time I add something (text, in my case), a Carriage Return is added. Here's what I did to address:

```
currentFooter = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text
If Right(currentFooter, 1) = vbCr Then
    newFooter = Left(currentFooter, Len(currentFooter) - 1)
End If
'then you make the changes you need to the truncated footer value and apply it back
    ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = newFooter
```